# How to disable Cognito user signups via CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

How can I select the "Only allow administrators to create users" value via CloudFormation on the AWS::Cognito::UserPool resource, or through some other method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set this via AllowAdminCreateUserOnly. Once that is set under General settings - Policies - Only allow administrators to create users should be checked.

```
  CognitoPool:
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
Properties:
  UserPoolName: TestPool
  AdminCreateUserConfig:
    AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: True
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-admincreateuserconfig.html